# Put update-like notification bubble on multiple CPTs menus for pending items

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

Much like how the Plugins or Comments menu items have these number notifications in a bubble for updates and unmoderated comments respectively, I'd like to use that bubble to display the number of CPTs which have a "Pending review" status. How to go about doing that?

I have found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/add-update-notification-bubble-to-admin-menu-item), but not quite sure where to go from there.

That would be neat to have; as I need this feature on a site that uses user-generated content (custom post types). Whenever users submit a new CPT, its status is set to "Pending review", and I want the site admins to quickly glance at the menu to see how many items need their attention.

**EDIT:** I now have this code:

```
// buuble notifications for custom posts with status pending
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_pending_bubble' );

function add_pending_bubble() {
    global $menu;

    $custom_post_count = wp_count_posts('custom-post-name');
    $custom_post_pending_count = $custom_post_count->pending;

    if ( $custom_post_pending_count ) {
        foreach ( $menu as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $menu[$key][2] == 'edit.php?post_type=custom-post-name' ) {
                $menu[$key][0] .= ' <span class="update-plugins count-' . $custom_post_pending_count . '"><span class="plugin-count">' . $custom_post_pending_count . '</span></span>';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...which does work, albeit a bit inconsistent. Sometimes displaying, sometimes not. Also, if I have multiple CPTs, how do I apply this code for each and every menu item of those CPTs? The above code will work with only one CPT.

Comment: The answer in your link explains it pretty well, you would instead store the pending items in a transient for your case, what code do you have?

Comment: Check this [other one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/71873/12615) too. But, yes, please, try to experiment with the code and post your own investigation here ;)

Comment: @Wyck I have updated my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made this work iterating through a post types list, and pinpointing the correct `$menu` key for the post type using a secondary function (instead of manually iterating through the `$menu` object).

[image: pending posts bubbles]

*Function reference: [`get_post_types`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) and [`wp_count_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts).*

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'pending_posts_bubble_wpse_89028', 999 );

function pending_posts_bubble_wpse_89028() 
{
    global $menu;

    // Get all post types and remove Attachments from the list
    // Add '_builtin' => false to exclude Posts and Pages
    $args = array( 'public' => true ); 
    $post_types = get_post_types( $args );
    unset( $post_types['attachment'] );

    foreach( $post_types as $pt )
    {
        // Count posts
        $cpt_count = wp_count_posts( $pt );

        if ( $cpt_count->pending ) 
        {
            // Menu link suffix, Post is different from the rest
            $suffix = ( 'post' == $pt ) ? '' : "?post_type=$pt";

            // Locate the key of 
            $key = recursive_array_search_php_91365( "edit.php$suffix", $menu );

            // Not found, just in case 
            if( !$key )
                return;

            // Modify menu item
            $menu[$key][0] .= sprintf(
                '<span class="update-plugins count-%1$s" style="background-color:white;color:black"><span class="plugin-count">%1$s</span></span>',
                $cpt_count->pending 
            );
        }
    }
}

// http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365
function recursive_array_search_php_91365( $needle, $haystack ) 
{
    foreach( $haystack as $key => $value ) 
    {
        $current_key = $key;
        if( 
            $needle === $value 
            OR ( 
                is_array( $value )
                && recursive_array_search_php_91365( $needle, $value ) !== false 
            )
        ) 
        {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes-- that works! For some reason though, the bubbles disappear when I click on the corresponding CPT menu item, but they reappear when I'm on other areas in wp-admin. Not gonna bother with that, problem solved.

Comment: In my test environment, the bubbles don't disappear, funny bug you got there... I like this thing :) and will wrap it inside a plugin with settings to select post types and status.

Comment: I suspect it's because of WPML. Using it to manage bilingual website, and I have essentially 2 versions of every post (cpt). That's why I sometimes see the bubble saying 2 where there is actually 1 pending post; because both posts synchronise their statuses. Hey, let me know about the plugin when you're done :D